# What does retag parameter in s/multi-spec mean?

Tags: clojure, multimethod, clojure.spec

Can you explain with examples how does `retag` parameter impacts `multi-spec` creation? I find `multi-spec` documentation hard to digest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docstring:

> retag is used during generation to retag generated values with
>   matching tags. retag can either be a keyword, at which key the
>   dispatch-tag will be assoc'ed, or a fn of generated value and
>   dispatch-tag that should return an appropriately retagged value.

If `retag` is a keyword (as in the [spec guide example](https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_multi_spec)), `multi-spec` internally creates a function [here](https://github.com/clojure/spec.alpha/blob/739c1af56dae621aedf1bb282025a0d676eff713/src/main/clojure/clojure/spec/alpha.clj#L902-L904) which is used in the generator implementation function. For example, these two multi-spec declarations are functionally equivalent:

```
(s/def :event/event (s/multi-spec event-type :event/type))
(s/def :event/event (s/multi-spec event-type
                                  (fn [genv tag]
                                    (assoc genv :event/type tag))))
```

Passing a `retag` *function* wouldn't seem like a very useful option given the guide's example, but is more useful when using `multi-spec` for non-maps. For example, if you wanted to use `multi-spec` with `s/cat` e.g. to spec function args:

```
(defmulti foo first)
(defmethod foo :so/one [_]
  (s/cat :typ #{:so/one} :num number?))
(defmethod foo :so/range [_]
  (s/cat :typ #{:so/range} :lo number? :hi number?))
```

`foo` takes either two or three args, depending on the first arg. If we try to `multi-spec` this naively using the `s/cat` keyword/tag, it won't work:

```
(s/def :so/foo (s/multi-spec foo :typ))
(sgen/sample (s/gen :so/foo))
;; ClassCastException clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Associative
```

This is where being able to pass a `retag` function is useful:

```
(s/def :so/foo (s/multi-spec foo (fn [genv _tag] genv)))
(sgen/sample (s/gen :so/foo))
;=>
;((:so/one -0.5)
; (:so/one -0.5)
; (:so/range -1 -2.0)
; (:so/one -1)
; (:so/one 2.0)
; (:so/range 1.875 -4)
; (:so/one -1)
; (:so/one 2.0)
; (:so/range 0 3)
; (:so/one 0.8125))
```

Comment: Thank you for great explanation and examples!

Answer (score 1):

I agree the docs are terse!

I wanted to generate a `multi-spec`d map with a tag which could have several values. I found that the second argument passed to the `retag` function is actually the **dispatch** tag, not the assigned tag (just like the docs say, in retrospect). This was causing `s/gen` to generate maps tagged with the (non-default) multimethod dispatch options only, not with the full ranged covered by the tag spec.

```
(s/def ::tag #{:a :b :c :d})
(s/def ::example-key keyword?)
(s/def ::different-key keyword?)

(defmulti tagmm :tag)
(defmethod tagmm :a [_]
  (s/keys :req-un [::tag ::example-key]))
(defmethod tagmm :default [_] ; this is `defmulti`'s :default
  (s/keys :req-un [::tag ::different-key]))

(s/def ::example (s/multi-spec tagmm :tag))

(gen/sample (s/gen ::example))
;=> only gives examples with {:tag :a, ...}
```

Providing a `retag` which just ignored its second argument and returned the generated value made the generator work as expected.

```
(s/def ::example (s/multi-spec tagmm (fn [gen-v tag] gen-v)))
;=> now gives examples from every ::tag
```

Hard to work out, but worth it!

Comment: I think if you have `(s/def ::tag keyword?)` then you can have `(s/def ::example (s/multi-spec tagmm ::tag))` (Note the qualified keyword!)